# How to Serialize a user defined function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle, dill

After reading a lot I got to know that pickle cant serialize a function or a class in Python(atleast in 3.6 version in windows). But I also saw a lot of people using `dill` for serialization. But when i tried i got errors. Below is the simple code that I used:

```
import dill
def cube(x):
    x**x**x

with open('outfile', 'wb') as pickle_file:
    dill.dump(cube, pickle_file)
```

And this is the error I got:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o0.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:279)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

To summarize my need of serializing is I want to use Serialization because I would like to use multiprocessing(Pool Class) in Python. After reading the documentation I go to know that pool class pickles the object to perform multiprocessing and as function or a class can't be pickled, pathos.multiprocessing library claims to do it as it uses dill to serialize. But when i used it gave me the error that I mentioned in my post

Can someone help me finding out the issue or let me know if there is some other way I can serialize a class or a function in Python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have an error full of ``py4j`` messages? Your shown code isn't using Py4j at all. What makes you think functions and classes cannot be pickled on Windows?

Comment: functions and classes can _sort of_ be pickled. If the code that's unpickling your data first imports all of the modules and classes that were being used by the code that pickled your data, then it should be able to reconstruct all your class instances correctly. But that may be a separate issue entirely from your `Py4JError`. I wouldn't expect the pickling process to crash regardless of the import situation.

Comment: Post us an MCVE (reproducible example) run in a clean shell without any py4j dependencies. Make sure to include all imports needed to run your example, but none that aren't actually needed to run it. If importing from py4j causes the issue, then that seems like a bug to report to py4j maintainers.

Answer (score -1):

Two simple approaches to serializing a function
would be to serialize its name and owning module name,
for subsequent use by `import`,
or to `dis` disassemble its bytecode.

This sounds like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):

> ... you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X [you ask about Y]

Feel free to ask us the *real* question, X.
There must be a higher level goal you're
trying to satisfy by serializing some notion
of "a function".
Ask a new question,
in which you show us the code you're working with.

Also, computing `x ** x ** x` is a very nice function,
but it's quite different from computing `x ** 3`.

EDIT

A classic difficulty with `multiprocessing` is
you wind up with an object that has a "hard to serialize"
attribute, such as an open TCP connection to a DB.
And then you create a Pool `p` and attempt `p.map( ... )`,
only to be told that certain things can't be serialized.
Well, the simplest fix is to avoid creating such things
in the first place, not before `p.map`.
Be lazy. Initialize them *after* `p.map` starts
executing your code in a child process.
Then there's no need for pickle or dill to ship
the crazy things to the child, since the child
can construct such things all by itself.

Comment: Do you have an example to illustrate? Thanks